# Can I optimize and speed up my VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am no VBA guru, but capable enough to stitch together the below code.  It essentially formats a Invoice to hide any empty rows (populated with vlookups, but no value returns ""), set to 1 page portrait and export to PDF.

My issue is:

1. The code is taking way to long to run from start to finish.

Below is the VBA code I want to optimize and speed up.

```
Sub Save_Quote_As_PDF()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim a As Long
For a = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
   On Error Resume Next
   With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(a)
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
Next a
On Error GoTo 0


ActiveSheet.Range("DCANUMBER").SpecialCells(4).EntireRow.Hidden = True


Dim PdfFilename As Variant

PdfFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("N2").Value, _
    FileFilter:="PDF, *.pdf", _
    Title:="Save As PDF")


If PdfFilename <> False Then

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .PrintArea = "$A$1:$K$78"
        .PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(19).Address
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With


    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=PdfFilename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End If


 ActiveSheet.Range("DCANUMBER").SpecialCells(4).EntireRow.Hidden = False

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: pushing the ranges to hide/unhide into a variable would speed up a bit...

Comment: I've not tried it but I'd imagine you could use the *Go To Special* F5 menu to select the blank cells and then the entire rows of those to then be hidden in one go rather than the loop would speed it up?

Comment: @TimEdwards only if the cells are empty for real... if there is a nullstring, then it will fail... also if he doesn't want any cells to stay hidden, he could use `ActiveSheet.Range("C20:C59").EntireRow.Hidden = False` to unhide...

Comment: True, we don't know if this was taken into consideration by the OP when they've used "" or not.

Comment: You could also add `Application.Calculation = False`  to the top and then put it to `True` at the end. (Like `ScreenUpdating`).  @DirkReichel - You mean even for the few times he uses a range, using a variable instead would make it *faster*?

Comment: Also this question may fit better into [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes dumping the range in a variant array, then cycling through the array and veryfing the condition, then at once showing/hiding all the rows that didn't pass the condition will be faster than doing it 30 times. Although I'm afraid the main time sink here is the PDF creation and we can't do anything about it.

Comment: the PDF creation is a time sink and so is the `PageSetup` - which is notoriously slow. Hiding all the rows at once will certainly help, but these two are not fixable.

Comment: is `For i = 20 To 59` really the slow part? I'd agree with everyone else, and in testing that loop worked relatively quickly as expected for me. You mentioned it would hide empty rows the doesn't it in fact show them? You could try this I guess `ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 3).EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 3) = "", True, False)`. The only other thing I can think of slowing this down is maybe you're running a large batch? This _could_ be a memory thing in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I updated the code above.  I removed the For i=20 to 59 section and replaced with special cell.  It seems that the formatting and exporting code is really the main drag.   Any suggestions on speeding up the pagesetup & export to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the blank rows:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet ' ActiveSheet is of type Object so using type Worksheet is a tiny bit faster

Dim row As Range ' again, specifying the type makes it a tiny bit faster
For Each row In ws.UsedRange.Rows    ' .UsedRange to limit the range to only the used range   
    If row.Find("*") Is Nothing Then
        row.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

I don't think that hiding the rows is the slowest part of your code. You should time your code to see what parts are the slowest:

```
Dim start As Single
start = Timer

' part of the code

Debug.Print CDbl(Timer - start), "part 1" ' CDbl to avoid scientific notation

start = Timer ' remember to reset the start time

' another part of the code

Debug.Print CDbl(Timer - start), "part 2"
```